# Custom Font not working?

Tags: css, three.js, custom-font

I am trying to add a custom font to me THREE.js scene, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work?

here is my css :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: : "Space";
  src: url("../font/space age.ttf") format("truetype");
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Space';
 }
```

Anyone have any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Have you checked in the console/network if the font request goes to 404?

Comment: You have two colons, which would be a compilation error: `font-family: : "Space";`. I'd also recommend removing the space from the URL.

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Remove colons in font-family in `@font-face` and in `body` and remove `format("truetype")`